# Dynamic Character Array - Stack

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, stack

I needed a character array containing a dynamic number of character arrays based on the number of files in a specific folder.  I was able to accomplish this by initializing char (*FullPathNames)[MAX_FILENAME_AND_PATHNAME_LENGTH] and then using FullPathNames = malloc( sizeof(*FullPathNames) * NumOfFiles * MAX_FILENAME_AND_PATHNAME_LENGTH ) ) after I know how many files another function discovered( which I have not provided). This process works flawlessly.

I can only use ANSI C; I am specifically using LabWindows CVI 8.1, to compile my code. I cannot use any other compiler.  The below code is doing what I want.   I can fill this array easily enough with the following code:

```
Strcpy(FullPathNames[0],”Test Word”);
char (*FullPathNames)[MAX_FILENAME_AND_PATHNAME_LENGTH];
size_t Size;
NumOfFiles = NumberOfUserFiles(“*.txt”, “C:\\ProgramData” );
FullPathNames = malloc( sizeof(*FullPathNames) * NumOfFiles * MAX_FILENAME_AND_PATHNAME_LENGTH ) );
Size = sizeof(*FullPathNames) * NumOfFiles;
Memset(FullPathNames,0,Size);
```

However, I would like to be able to pass `FullPathNames` which is an array of pointers to a variable amount of character arrays into a method.  I want this method to be able to remove a single character array at a given index.

I am calling the method with the following code.

```
Remove_Element(FullPathNames,1, NumOfFiles);
```

The code for Remove_Element:

```
void Remove_Element( char (*Array)[MAX_FILENAME_AND_PATHNAME_LEN], int Index, int Array_Length )    
{
  int i;    
  char String[MAX_FILENAME_AND_PATHNAME_LEN];        
  char (*NewArray)[MAX_FILENAME_AND_PATHNAME_LEN];    
  int NewLength = Array_Length - 1;    
  size_t Size;

NewArray = malloc( sizeof( *NewArray) *  NewLength * ( MAX_FILENAME_AND_PATHNAME_LEN ) );

Size = sizeof( *NewArray ) * NewLength; 

memset(NewArray, 0, Size);
  for ( i = Index; i < Array_Length - 1; i++ )    
  {

    memcpy(String,Array[i+1],MAX_FILENAME_AND_PATHNAME_LEN); // Remove last index to avoid duplication

    strcpy( Array[Index], String );     
  } 
  Array = NewArray;     
}
```

My expectation of what I have currently is that the original data of FullPathNames remains except for the index that I removed, by copying data from `index + 1`, and the original pointers contained within FullPathNames is of course updated.  Since I also wanted to shrink the array I attempted to set the array equal to the new array.  The following information explains my attempts at debugging this behavior.

The watch variables present the following information as I enter the method.

```
FullPathNames = XXXXXX
NewArray = Unallocated
Array = XXXXXX
```

After I fill the new temporary Array the following happens:

```
FullPathNames = XXXXXX
NewArray = YYYYY
Array = XXXXXX
```

As I exit the method the following happens:

```
FullPathNames = XXXXXX
NewArray = YYYYY
Array = YYYYY
```

I was attempting to modify `FullPathNames` by passing it in as a pointer.  I originally tried this task by using **realloc** but that just resulted in a free pointer exception.

Notes:
MAX_FILENAME_AND_PATHNAME_LENGTH = 516;

Answer (score -3, accepted):

A working variation of my solution appears below.  The reason I had to do it this way is because while I was able to dereference `(**Array)[MAX_FILENAME_AND_PATHNAME_LEN]` I was only able to modify the first string array in the array.

The string array was initialized and filled several strings.  While I could reference a string contained within `*Array[0]` but was unable to reference any of the other strings.  The resulting array will replace the original array.  This method will only work in the initial code block where the array to be replaced is initialized.

```
#define MAX_FILENAME_AND_PATHNAME_LEN MAX_FILENAME_LEN + MAX_PATHNAME_LEN


/*

    This method was designed to free the memory allocated to an array.

*/
void FreeFileAndPathArrays( char (*Array)[MAX_FILENAME_AND_PATHNAME_LEN] )
{   
    free( Array );
}                 

/*

    This method was designed to remove an index from an array.  The result of this method will shrink the array by one.

*/
void Remove_Element( char (**ArrayPointer)[MAX_FILENAME_AND_PATHNAME_LEN],int Index, int *Array_Length, char (*Array)[MAX_FILENAME_AND_PATHNAME_LEN] )
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    char String[MAX_FILENAME_AND_PATHNAME_LEN];    
    char (*NewArray)[MAX_FILENAME_AND_PATHNAME_LEN];
    char (*GC)[MAX_FILENAME_AND_PATHNAME_LEN];
    int Length = *Array_Length;
    int NewLength = Length - 1;
    size_t Size;
    
    NewArray = malloc( sizeof( *NewArray) *  NewLength * ( MAX_FILENAME_AND_PATHNAME_LEN ) );
    
    Size = sizeof( *NewArray ) * NewLength;
    memset(NewArray, 0, Size);
    UI_Display("Test Block:");
    
    for ( j = 0; j < NewLength; j++ )
    {
        if ( j != Index )
        {
            memcpy(String,Array[j],MAX_FILENAME_AND_PATHNAME_LEN);
            strcpy( Array[Index], String ); 
            Fill(NewArray,String,j);
            UI_Display(String);
        }
    }

    GC = Array;
    *ArrayPointer = NewArray;
    free(GC);          
    *Array_Length = *Array_Length - 1;
    
}

/*

    This method was designed to place a string into an index.

*/
void Fill( char (*Array)[MAX_FILENAME_AND_PATHNAME_LEN], const char * String, int Index)
{  
        strcpy( Array[Index], String ); 
}

/*

    This method was designed to place fill each string array contained within the array of string arrays with 0's.

*/
void PrepareFileAndPathArrays( char (*FullPathNames)[MAX_FILENAME_AND_PATHNAME_LEN], int ROWS )
{
    size_t Size;
    
    Size = sizeof( *FullPathNames ) * ROWS;
    memset(FullPathNames, 0, Size);
  
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, what you want to do is to modify the FullPathNames Pointer in the code part where you initialize your original array.

With your declartion of FullPatchNames

```
char (*FullPathNames)[MAX_FILENAME_AND_PATHNAME_LENGTH]
```

you basically declare a pointer to an array of MAX_FILENAME_AND_PATHNAME_LENGTH char elements. With your call to `void Remove_Element(...)` you just give a copy of this pointer to the local variable `Array` valid inside your function. Because of this `Array = NewArray;`, only changes the local copy of your pointer inside the function, not `FullPathNames`.

If you want to change the value of `FullPathNames` you must give a pointer to this pointer to your function. The Prototype of `Remove_Element` must look like this:

```
 void Remove_Element( char (**Array)[MAX_FILENAME_AND_PATHNAME_LEN],
                      int Index, int Array_Length )
```

Now Array is a Pointer to an Pointer to an (one dimansional) array of char. By dereferencing this Pointer, you can change your original Pointer FullPathNames to point to your new object you created inside your function. You must modify the call to this function to `Remove_Element(&FullPathNames,1, NumOfFiles);`. To read from Array, you must dereference it using the * operator:

```
memcpy(String,*Array[i+1],MAX_FILENAME_AND_PATHNAME_LEN);
...
Array = NewArray;
```

**Warning:** This code will now produce a memory leak, since you are loosing your reference to your orignal object. You should remove this using the free() function somewhere in your code!

Answer (score 2):

There seems to exist a certain lack of knowledge about the syntax in C language first and foremost.

```
char (*FullPathNames)[MAX_FILENAME_AND_PATHNAME_LENGTH]
```

This is one example. The syntax shown here would be read by a c- programmer as:

- Semicolon is missing - maybe #define voodoo somewhere!
- char (*FullPathNames)... - a function pointer! oh wait why square brackets next?!
- Maybe he wanted to say `char *FullPathNames;` or he wanted `char FullPathNames[MAX_FILENAME_AND_PATH_NAME_LENGTH];` Hm...

So here the first 101:

```
char foo[50]; // A fixed size array with capacity 50 (49 chars + '\0' max).
char *foo = NULL; // a uninitialized pointer to some char.
char (*foo)(); // a pointer to a function of signature: char(void).
char *foobar[50]; // This is an array of 50 pointers to char.
```

Depending on where your `char foo[50];` is located (in the code file, in a function, in a structure definition), the storage used for it varies.

```
char foo1[50]; // zerovars section.
char foo2[50] = { 0 }; // initvars section
char foo3[50] = "Hello World!"; // also initvars section

void FooTheFoo( const char *foo )
{
     if(NULL != foo )
     {
          printf("foo = %s\n", foo);
     }
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{ 
    char bar[50] = "Message from the past."; // bar is located on the stack (automatic variable).
    FooTheFoo(bar); // fixed size array or dynamic array - passed as a (const pointer) in C.
    return 0;
}
```

Now we got the basics down, lets look at 2-dimensional dynamic array.
`char **matrix = NULL;`
A pointer to a pointer of char. Or a pointer to an array of pointers to chars or an array of pointers to pointers to arrays of chars.

As lined out, there is no "meta" information regarding to what a `char*` or a `char **` point to beyond that finally the dereferenced item will be of type char. And that it is a pointer to a pointer.

If you want to make a 2-dimensional array out of it, you have to initialize accordingly:

```
const size_t ROW_COUNT = 5;
const size_T COL_COUNT = 10;
char **myMatrix = malloc(sizeof(char *) * ROW_COUNT);
// check if malloc returned NULL of course!
if( NULL != myMatrix )
{
    for(size_t row = 0; row < ROW_COUNT; row++ )
    {
         myMatrix[row] = malloc(sizeof(char) * COL_COUNT);
         if( NULL == myMatrix[row] ) PanicAndCryOutLoudInDespair();
         for(size_t col = 0; col < COL_COUNT; col++ )
         {
              myMatrix[row][col] = 0;
         }
         // of course you could also write instead of inner for - loop:
         // memset(myMatrix[row], 0, sizeof(char) * COL_COUNT);

    }
}
```

Last not least, how to pass such a 2-dimensional array to a function? As the char** construct does not contain the meta information regarding sizes, in the general (inner not a 0 terminated string) case, you would do it like that:

```
void FooIt( const char **matrix, size_t rowCount, size_t colCount )
{    // Note: standard checks omitted! (NULL != matrix, ...)
     putchar(matrix[0][0]);
}
```

Last, if you want to get rid of your 2D dynamic array again, you need to properly free it.

```
void Cleanup2DArray( char **matrix, size_t rowCount )
{
    for(size_t row = 0; row < rowCount; row++ )
    {
         free(matrix[row];
    }
    free(matrix);
}
```

The only thing more to say about it I leave to other gentle contributors. One thing coming to mind is how to express const-ness correctly for those multi-dimensional things.

```
const char **
const char const * const *
etc.
```

With this, you should be able to spot the places where you went wrong in your code and fix it.

Answer (score 2):

The pointer you're passing is *just a value*. That it holds an address means you can dereference it to modify what it *points to*, but it doesn't mean changing its value directly (your assignment statement) will affect the caller-parameter. Like everything else in C, if you want to modify something by-address, then an address is exactly what you need to do it. If the thing you're modifying is a pointer, then the address of the pointer (through a pointer-to-pointer parameter) is the generally prescribed solution.

However, I can tell you the syntax and housekeeping to do that is... uninviting in your case. A simple pointer is easy enough, but a pointer-to-array-of-N isn't so simply. Were I you his would simply use the return result of the function itself, which is otherwise currently being unused and `void`. Declare your function like this:

```
char (*Remove_Element( char (*Array)[MAX_FILENAME_AND_PATHNAME_LEN], 
    int Index, int Array_Length ))[MAX_FILENAME_AND_PATHNAME_LEN]
{
    ....

    return Array; // or whatever else you want to return so
                  // long as the type is correct.
}
```

and simply have the caller do this:

```
Array = RemoveElement(Array, Index, Array_Length);
```